# Eager load associations in nested set model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using nested set to represent nested comments (1 discussion which has many comments, the comments can be replied to) and I would like to (if possible) to eager load the answers to comments.

At the moment I load all root nodes and iterate over them, if they have descendants I render them. However, if there are a lot of root nodes with answers, this triggers a lot of DB requests.

A comment has these columns:
`rgt, lft, parent_id`

I tried to create a relationship like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, -> (node) { where("lft > ? AND rgt < ?", node.lft, node.rgt) }, class_name: "Comment", foreign_key: :parent_id
end
```

This fetches the answers to a comment when called on a Comment instance. However, if I try to eager_load it (`Discussion.comments.includes(:answers)`) it blows up since `node` is nil.

Is it possible to eager load something like this?

Comment: What's `node`? What are _"all root nodes"_? Why does your `has_many :answers` have `class_name: "Comment"` in it?

Comment: my guess is he has a common model in mind for answers and comments. just a different name. :P

Comment: A Comment belongs to a Discussion (doesn't really matter). A Comment has many answers (replies) which are also Comments. a root node is a Comments which is not an answer (reply) to another Comment (parent_id = nil).

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about using nested set (that probably should be in the title :) Are you using a nested set gem?

Comment: @smathy Yes, thank you for editing the title. Yes, I'm using the awesome_nested_set gem and they don't support eager loading descendants. Here is an issue I have open there: https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/issues/271

Comment: Don't they have a `.children` method that returns all children for a node?

Answer (score 1):

I think, I've found a solution. 
If I see it right, your data model looks like this:

```
Discussion
----------
...

Comment
----------
discussion_id:int
parent_id:int
lft:int
rgt:int
```

Then AR model classes will be:

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :discussion
end
```

To eager load discussion (id == 1) with all its tree of comments and answers use:

```
d = Discussion.includes(:comments).find(1)
```

This gives a collection of all comments for given discussion in memory (`d.comments`).

Now we can manipulate this collection to get answers for any particular comment without additional DB queries. Just add this to `Discussion` class:

```
def comment_roots
  self.comments.select {|c| c.parent_id.nil? }
end
```

and this to `Comment` class:

```
  def answers
    self.discussion.comments.select {|c| c.parent_id = self.id }
  end

  def answers_tree
    self.discussion.comments.select {|c| self.lft < c.lft && c.rgt <   self.rgt }
  end
```

Example:

```
d.comment_roots.first.answers
```